Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function pll_current_language()
When I try to call any function of the Polylang plugin in the site theme, I get a critical error. Plugin version: 3.6 For example:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function pll_current_language() in
/var/www/rue_ee_usr/data/www/rue.ee/wp-content/themes/hostcluster/search.php:40
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/rue_ee_usr/data/www/rue.ee/wp-includes/template-loader.php(106): include()
#1 /var/www/rue_ee_usr/data/www/rue.ee/wp-blog-header.php(19):  require_once('/var/www/rue_ee...')
#2 /var/www/rue_ee_usr/data/www/rue.ee/index.php(17): require('/var/www/rue_ee...')
#3 {main} thrown in /var/www/rue_ee_usr/data/www/rue.ee/wp-content/themes/hostcluster/search.php on line 40

How to fix it?
Plugin is activated. In the site theme I tried to get information about the plugin:
if ( class_exists( 'Polylang' ) ) {
    print "Polylang plugin is exists!";
} else {
    print "Polylang plugin not exists!";
}

In the site i get "Polylang plugin not exists!"

Try to execute above code under action hook, for example add_action('init', 'init_callback') and your code will go within function init_callback(){}. This may be issue due to the priority of hooks execution
